# Crash App android Activity t40}}} timed out

Tags: java, android

I Created an application in Eclipse and it is working fine on lots of phones, but on few phones it crashes when loaded

my red log cat is below:

```
07-04 13:39:55.865: E/WindowManager(1048): Starting window AppWindowToken{42bcf4f0 token=Token{42bc5a70 ActivityRecord{4276f370 u0 com.iran.sunni.times.azan.alarms/com.iran.sunni.times.azan.alarm.PrayerTimeActivity t40}}} timed out
07-04 13:39:56.025: E/Parcel(528): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-04 13:39:56.025: E/Parcel(528): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-04 13:40:10.425: E/Sensors(1048): Recevied Proximity Sensor pollEvents
07-04 13:40:10.425: E/Sensors(1048): Recevied Proximity Sensor pollEvents
07-04 13:40:10.425: E/Sensors(1048): Recevied Proximity Sensor pollEvents
07-04 13:40:10.435: E/Sensors(1048): Recevied Proximity Sensor pollEvents
```

Answer (score 2):

You're taking too long on the main thread in your onCreate function.  Your app needs to launch within a few seconds or Android assumes its broken. Without code I have no idea what's taking so long, you'll have to look into that.

Comment: which file i should check? Please tell me , ill paste here for you codes

Comment: Prayer time activity. The onCreate most likely

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Gabe, you are doing too much work at OnCreate. Move all those functions read file and so on to a background thread and show a progress dialog to the user (code between lines 314 - 322) Your app takes to long to start and android kills it. Will edit the answer with an example as soon as i start my pc.

Comment: thanks, can i have your s-kype ID so we can make it together and then we will post it here...

Comment: I have not forgot. I will let you know in a few

Comment: thanks, please edit source for me so its better for understanding

Answer (score 0):

clearly there is a problem in your ajustTime() method.

```
public void ajustTime() {
    {
        String dtFajarSetting = Settings.storeData.getTextData("At0");
        if (!dtFajarSetting.equals("")) {
            String[] dnValue = dtFajarSetting.split(",");
            int index = Integer.parseInt(dnValue[0]);
            int totalMin = Integer.parseInt(dnValue[1]);
            paryerData.add(index, addMin(totalMin, paryerData.get(index)));
            paryerData.remove(index + 1);
        }
    }
```

chek your index and totlaMin in Logcat like this

```
Log.d("Check","Index = "+ index +"totalMin=" +totalMin);
```

in ajustTime() method to if they are null or not.

Comment: i comment out "ajustTime();" in "prayertimeactivity.java" but no effective